# MySQL adding columns with a particular id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

- One is some kind of a customer table where id and name is stored.
- The second one is a item table where id, name and price is stored.
- The third one combines ids of both with a quantity.

My question is how I can `SELECT` a name of a customer with a total price of all items he want to buy.

```
    SELECT 
        first.name, third.quantity * second.price 
    FROM
        first 
    LEFT JOIN
        third ON third.fID = first.ID 
    LEFT JOIN
        second ON second.ID = third.sID ;
```

This what I have. It selects all items with a total price but I need to add them for every customer.

E.g. it returns:

```
  customer1 5000
  customer2 100
  customer1 1000
```

but I want:

```
  customer1 6000
  customer2 100
```

Comment: use aggregate functions like `sum()` and `group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want an aggregation query with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT first.name, SUM(third.quantity *  second.price)
FROM first LEFT JOIN
     third 
     ON third.fID = first.ID LEFT JOIN
     second 
     ON second.ID = third.sID
GROUP BY first.name;
```

Comment: Ahh.. i allready tried it but i had an 'AS' in the brackets... Thanks